# Not able to understand how the promise data is interpreted in the below code snippet

Tags: javascript, amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb, aws-sdk, aws-sdk-nodejs

Here in the below code snippet I'm not sure how the promise is consumed cause for the line **const result = await dynamodb.scan(scanParams).promise();** I think the result will either be resolved or rejected promise which is why I'm not sure why we are using the await keyword in this line **items: await result.Items.map((customer) => {** and can't directly access the Items without using the **await** keyword:

```
'use strict';
const AWS = require('aws-sdk');
 
module.exports.getCustomers = async (event) => {
  const scanParams = {
    TableName: process.env.DYNAMODB_CUSTOMER_TABLE,
  };
 
  const dynamodb = new AWS.DynamoDB.DocumentClient();
  const result = await dynamodb.scan(scanParams).promise();
 
  if (result.Count === 0) {
    return {
      statusCode: 404,
    };
  }
 
  return {
    statusCode: 200,
    body: JSON.stringify({
      total: result.Count,
      items: await result.Items.map((customer) => {
        return {
          name: customer.primary_key,
          email: customer.email,
        };
      }),
    }),
  };
};
```

Comment: It depends what Items is. If it's a vanilla array the await is pointless, but maybe its map method does return a promise.

Comment: Thanks for your reply! Here .promise() will promisify the dynamoDB scan() method results and we are consuming it and at the same time returning it. So, assuming that Items return a promise() then can we directly access the Items using the map method without actually waiting for the promise() and consuming it after awaiting for it?

Comment: You should not be using await in `await result.Items.map(...)`. There are no promises in that line of code. Also, note that the number of items returned by scan is limited, so be aware of the potential need to paginate results.

Comment: If `result.Items` is a promise, you should use `(await result.Items).map(...)`.